# Add fe_user uid as parameter to redirect URL

Tags: typo3

I have a header location redirect if a user is logged in.

Now I want to add the fe_user uid as a get parameter to the link, but it doesn't work. How could I solve this?

What i tried so far:

```
config {
  additionalHeaders {
    #10.data = TSFE:fe_user|user|username
    10.header = Location: https://mydomain.de?userId={TSFE:fe_user|user|username}
  }
config.additionalHeaders.10.header.insertData = 1
}
```

Comment: Maybe because `config.additionalHeaders.10.header.insertData = 1` needs to be placed either after the last closing bracket or just with `10.header.insertData = 1` after the `10.header =` line?

Comment: Are you sure, `header` has stdWrap-properties, so `insertData` will be interpreted? https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Setup/Config/Index.html#additionalheaders sounds, like `header` is only simple text: "header: The header string"

Comment: Is there another way to integrate? For example with an temp.var?

Comment: I would use a `userFunc`, plugin controller or Middleware to do the redirect. I've checked felogin for hook possiblities to alter the redirect URL but did not find any.